# MATLAB error - "Error using symengine Input arguments must be convertible to floating-point numbers"

Tags: matlab, max, piecewise

Im writing a MATLAB code to animate a grashof four bar mechanism but my animation is running only till the 15th iteration and coming back with this error
**Error using symengine
Input arguments must be convertible to floating-point numbers.

Error in sym/mupadmexnout (line 1116)
out = mupadmex(fcn,args{:});

Error in sym/max (line 182)
[C,I] = mupadmexnout('symobj::maxmin',Xsym, dim,'max', nanflag);

Related documentation**

Is there a way to use peicewise instead of max in this scenario where both args are unknown?
Your help and suggestions are much appreciated. Yhank You
The code is attached below

```
a=1.6;
b=2.14;
c=2.06;
d=3.5;
AB=a
BC=b
CD=c
AD=d
xa=0;
ya=0;
yd=0;
xd=AD;
t2=0
for ii=1:36
    syms t3 t4


    t2=t2+10
    f=a*cosd(t2) + b*cosd(t3) - c*cosd(t4) -3.5

    g=a*sind(t2) + b*sind(t3) - c*sind(t4)

    [t31, t41]=(solve(f==0,g==0,t3,t4))
    var = vpa(t31)

    th3=double((max(t31)))

    th4=double((max(t41)))
    
    if exist('th3', 'var') 
        xb(ii)=AB*cosd(t2);
        yb(ii)=AB*sind(t2);
        xc(ii)=xb(ii)  + BC*cosd(th3)
        yc(ii)=yb(ii)  + BC*sind(th3)
        
        plot(xa,ya,'k.',xb,yb,'b.',xc,yc,'g.',xd,yd,'c.',LineWidth=3)
        hold on
        axis equal
        line_plot1 = plot([xa,xb(ii)], [ya,yb(ii)], 'b',LineWidth=3);
        line_plot2 = plot([xb(ii),xc(ii)], [yb(ii),yc(ii)], 'r',LineWidth=3);
        line_plot3 = plot([xc(ii),xd], [yc(ii),yd], 'm',LineWidth=3);
        line_plot4 = plot([xd,xa], [yd,ya], 'c',LineWidth=3);
        axis equal
        hold off
        pause(0.06)
    else
        continue
    end
end

`
```

Answer (score 0):

at iteration 15 assumes value: -

> (360*atan(((290977643440946361463614464*3^(1/2))/16381 -
> (35869579695136164170619*(- (1085424178048*3^(1/2))/65205930123 -
> 803672842364/65205930123)^(1/2))/2 -
> 20415849832326625912368*3^(1/2)*((-
> (1085424178048*3^(1/2))/65205930123 -
> 803672842364/65205930123)^(1/2)/2 - (210944*3^(1/2))/442287 +
> 1648/147429) +
> 11759769043149622934890992/16381)/(233159481474211118318352*3^(1/2) +
> 401972381605023123837879)))/pi
>
> -(360*atan(((290977643440946361463614464*3^(1/2))/16381 + (35869579695136164170619*(- (1085424178048*3^(1/2))/65205930123 -
> 803672842364/65205930123)^(1/2))/2 +
> 20415849832326625912368*3^(1/2)*((210944*3^(1/2))/442287 + (-
> (1085424178048*3^(1/2))/65205930123 -
> 803672842364/65205930123)^(1/2)/2 - 1648/147429) +
> 11759769043149622934890992/16381)/(233159481474211118318

Basically solve does not return a number but an expression, what you can do is use
[vpa](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) to numerically solve the expression and pass it to `max()`

adding the the following lines after the solve should do the trick:

```
     t31 = vpa(t31)
     t41 = vpa(t41)
```

The final code would be:

```
a=1.6;
b=2.14;
c=2.06;
d=3.5;
AB=a
BC=b
CD=c
AD=d
xa=0;
ya=0;
yd=0;
xd=AD;
t2=0
syms t3 t4
for ii=1:36



    t2=t2+10
    f=a*cosd(t2) + b*cosd(t3) - c*cosd(t4) -3.5

    g=a*sind(t2) + b*sind(t3) - c*sind(t4)

    [t31, t41]=(solve(f==0,g==0,t3,t4))

    t31 = vpa(t31)
    t41 = vpa(t41)
    
    th3=double((max(t31)))

    th4=double((max(t41)))
    
    if exist('th3', 'var') 
        xb(ii)=AB*cosd(t2);
        yb(ii)=AB*sind(t2);
        xc(ii)=xb(ii)  + BC*cosd(th3)
        yc(ii)=yb(ii)  + BC*sind(th3)
        
        plot(xa,ya,'k.',xb,yb,'b.',xc,yc,'g.',xd,yd,'c.',LineWidth=3)
        hold on
        axis equal
        line_plot1 = plot([xa,xb(ii)], [ya,yb(ii)], 'b',LineWidth=3);
        line_plot2 = plot([xb(ii),xc(ii)], [yb(ii),yc(ii)], 'r',LineWidth=3);
        line_plot3 = plot([xc(ii),xd], [yc(ii),yd], 'm',LineWidth=3);
        line_plot4 = plot([xd,xa], [yd,ya], 'c',LineWidth=3);
        axis equal
        hold off
        pause(0.06)
    else
        continue
    end
end
```